# How to create a button under message with telethon while logged in as user

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I'm learning how to use telethon while logged in as user. Currently i have some trouble with creating inline button. My code is:

```
@register(outgoing=True, pattern="^\.button(?: |$)(.*)")
async def buttontest(test):
    await test.client.send_message(test.chat_id, 'click me', buttons=[Button.inline('Test', 'test-return')])
```

When i use this, i only see a "click me" message, without a button. Are buttons applicable while using telethon as user?

Comment: User accounts cannot include buttons on messages on their own. They would need to rely on a bot's help and send it via them.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot send a inline buttons as a user. Try sending them via bots. Telegram limits certain type of actions usable only by bots like the inline query, buttons etc..